# Other ways to force another round of C macro expansion?

Tags: c, error-handling, syntax, macros, preprocessor

I have a C macro library that injects error handling in an unobtrusive way, by defining _(...).  I want to extend the library with a function (a macro actually) that wraps some additional complexity but can still be used with the error handling injection macro... but this seems not to work as I hit a problem with nested/recursive macro expansion.

I've worked around this by writing a "compromise" macro to force the extra level of macro expansion that I need, but it is less than perfect because it deviates from the usual syntax for injecting error handling (refer to last line in the following example code).

Example C code:

```
#define _(...) (__VA_ARGS__); check_and_handle_errno()
#define DO(x, ...) (x ? do_impl(static_arg, __VA_ARGS__) : NULL)
#define DO_(x, ...) _(x ? do_impl(static_arg, __VA_ARGS__) : NULL)

type * name = do_impl(static_arg, arg2);  // no error handling
type * name = do_impl _(static_arg, arg2);  // with error handling

// a bit more complex
type * name = (arg1 ? do_impl(static_arg, arg2) : NULL);  // no error handling
type * name = _(arg1 ? do_impl(static_arg, arg2) : NULL);  // with error handling

// complexity wrapped by macro
type * name = DO(arg1, arg2);  // no error handling
type * name = DO _(arg1, arg2);  // with error handling, but doesn't fully expand
type * name = DO_(arg1, arg2);  // compromise, but I really want the syntax above
```

When saved to a file (test.h) and run through the preprocessor via `gcc -E test.h`, the example gets converted into the following:

```
type * name = do_impl(static_arg, arg2);
type * name = do_impl (static_arg, arg2); check_and_handle_errno();

type * name = (arg1 ? do_impl(static_arg, arg2) : NULL);
type * name = (arg1 ? do_impl(static_arg, arg2) : NULL); check_and_handle_errno();

type * name = (arg1 ? do_impl(static_arg, arg2) : NULL);
type * name = DO (arg1, arg2); check_and_handle_errno();
type * name = (arg1 ? do_impl(static_arg, arg2) : NULL); check_and_handle_errno();
```

Does anybody know how to achieve the syntax in the 2nd to last line in the example code (and have it expand to the last line in the example)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your desired syntax is possible, it doesn't seem to be - but logically, what you're trying to accomplish is equivalent to:

`type * name = _(DO(arg1, arg2));`

that is, first execute `arg2` if `arg1` is true, and then check the error.

This works without a third `DO_` macro and isn't far off from what you seem to want.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I think you are right: my desired syntax isn't possible using a macro to wrap the complexity, but I think it is possible if I used a small function instead.  Still I'm accepting your answer.  Your observation that `_(DO(...))` is functionally equivalent is great (I didn't spot that!) and can be used to simplify my MACRO_ convention, for example: `#define DO_(...) _(DO(__VA_ARGS__))`